# Looking for reliable way to know if my phone is home or not

Tags: php, api, gps

I want my garage door to open automatically, hand-free when my phone is detected upon arrival after being away more than 1 hour.

I have PHP code to open the garage door when GET or POST'ing a URL for it.   I have PHP logic (using wifi at home) to determine if my phone is home or not and will only open the garage door if I've been gone more than an hour and then it sees my phone reappearing.

I can't rely as my wifi (using Ubiquiti UniFi contorller) seeing my phone because it's too slow to detect my arrival and departure. It's about 1 minute slow seeing my phone and 5 min slow seeing my phone left.  I am looking for other options:

-Bluetooth:  I normally hate it, but could it trigger from like 30 feet so the door opens in time?

-GPS:  Google and Motorola have websites to track my phone location, but I don't seem to be able to tap into their data.  I'd love to check every 1 min to see if my phone is at home via cron and PHP.

-Do I have my PHP looping through, looking at my phones location and trigger when home, or do I have something running on my phone that triggers when home and GET/POSTs the open garage door URL?

Comment: did you know about `IFTTT`? look at it i think it will help you on this.
https://ifttt.com/discover

Comment: There is an app that is a perfect fit for you called Llama for Android. You will also need to install the Llama GPS add on to pinpoint a position when the phone does an action (opens the web browser that opens the door).  I believe the path you are trying will not be satisfying.

Comment: IFTTT is new to me, but I'll have to check it out more.

Comment: Llama sound interesting.  I hope it really whips the llamas ass.   Anyway, if it can GET or POST upon GPS location, that works.  I don't need to see it load a page in a browser, just hit it.

Comment: I'm quite sure it can use GET at least. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer you are looking for. But [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) with some configuration will do what you want to do. You will not be coding in PHP, but it will require you to configure some stuff.

Set up a [device tracker](https://www.home-assistant.io/components/device_tracker/) on your devices and create automations.

Comment: Do you think it can GET or POST a webpage based on GPS location?   I don't need to view the page, just hit it.

Comment: I have not yet tested it myself. But I believe the [Coomand line Switch](https://www.home-assistant.io/components/switch.command_line/) can be used by issuing a command to cURL, which will help you create both GET and POST requests. The [Home Assistant Discord](https://discord.gg/c5DvZ4e) has been a valuable resource for me, you will probably find someone with more knowledge than me there.

Answer (score 0):

People have been helpful, however I didn't choose the suggesested solutions because of the following because there were dead (like llama) or fully formed projects not really doing what I needed (fast and accurate phone location for 'home').

I tried going llama, but after discovering it's a dead project, I went with the 'Tasker' app.   I can use it to scan wifi ever 30 seconds (or whatever I set) and if it sees my home SSID, send a HTTP GET to my website.  On my website, it receives the HTTP get with PHP and does the logic to determine that if I've been gone more than an hour, then send the HTTP GET to open the garage door.   I could have done this all with Tasker probably.  But I'd rather write 30 lines of PHP to do logic on opening the door or not, than try to figure out how to type similar logic into the mobile app.